# How to check for substring across a DataFrame using lists of possible matches

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-transform

I have existing code that I would like to keep, up to this point I have been searching on exact matches for my codes but have discovered that I should be searching for anything starting with the codes below.

I hope to change the for loop on the `idx` dictionary so I can look for matches that start with the codes provided, therefore I want to replace the `isin` with say something like `contains` but obviously can't do that with a Pandas DataFrame.

Because of exactly matching I have been underestimating the frequency counts as a result, is there another method/function to use so I can reserve this code?

```
# Create Dataframe
patients = [('pat1', 'C77', 'F01', 'M32', 'M315'),
         ('pat2', 'I099', 'I278', 'M05', 'F01'),
         ('pat3', 'N057', 'N057', 'N058', 'N057')]
labels = ['patient_num', 'DIAGX1', 'DIAGX2', 'DIAGX3', 'DIAGX4']

df_patients = pd.DataFrame.from_records(patients, columns=labels)
df_patients

Input
patient_num DIAGX1  DIAGX2  DIAGX3  DIAGX4
pat1        C77     F01     M32     M315
pat2        I099    I278    M05     F01
pat3        N057    N057    N058    N057

Output
patient_num DIAGX1  DIAGX2  DIAGX3  DIAGX4  dementia_yn  tumour_yn
pat1        C77     F01     M32     M315    1            1
pat2        I099    I278    M05     F01     1            0
pat3        N057    N057    N058    N057    0            0

dementia = ["F01", "F02", "F03", "F051", "G30", "G311"]
rheumatologic_disease = ["M05", "M06", "M315", "M32", "M33", "M34", "M351", "M353", "M360"]

idx = {
    "dementia": dementia,
    "rheumatologic_disease": rheumatologic_disease
}


for condition, codes in idx.items():
    df_pan[condition + "_yn"] = df_pan.isin(codes).any(axis=1).astype(int)
```

Comment: you can do "contains" in pandas : df['col'].str.contains('my_string') returns a Series with True or False for each row. If I understand what you want to do, this is what you should use (along with any(axis=1))

Comment: @Vincent This would be great but when I try and apply the `.st.contains() method I get an error stating I can't apply this to a DataFrame and I am not sure how to loop over columns and correctly and reference only columns containing strings.

Answer (score 0):

To test if the start of each string element matches a pattern, I would recommend using [str.startswith](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith).

With the following setup:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    [
        ("pat1", "C77", "F01", "M32", "M315"),
        ("pat2", "I099", "I278", "M05", "F01"),
        ("pat3", "N057", "N057", "N058", "F01"),
    ],
    columns=["patient_num", "DIAGX1", "DIAGX2", "DIAGX3", "DIAGX4"],
)

idx = {
    "dementia": ["F01", "F02", "F03", "F051", "G30", "G311"],
    "rheumatologic_disease": [
        "M05",
        "M06",
        "M315",
        "M32",
        "M33",
        "M34",
        "M351",
        "M353",
        "M360",
    ],
}
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
for condition, codes in idx.items():
    df[f"{condition}_yn"] = pd.concat(
        [
            df[["DIAGX1", "DIAGX2", "DIAGX3", "DIAGX4"]].apply(
                lambda x: 1 if x.str.startswith(code).any() else 0, axis=1
            )
            for code in codes
        ],
        axis=1,
    ).sum(axis=1)
```

```py
print(df)
# Output
  patient_num DIAGX1 DIAGX2 DIAGX3 DIAGX4  dementia_yn  rheumatologic_disease_yn
0        pat1    C77    F01    M32   M315            1                         2
1        pat2   I099   I278    M05    F01            1                         1
2        pat3   N057   N057   N058   N057            0                         0
```